# How can I get certificate_id and client_id in AWS IoT Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-iot

I am using AWS IoT Core. I've created client side certificate for the device following https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/just-in-time-registration-of-device-certificates-on-aws-iot/. Everything went fine. Problem is that now I want to save client certificate_id and client_id in same table to make a relation between them, but I could not get certificate_id and client_id in one lambda invokation.
for example:

- when device make first time conection with its client certificate to IoT server, lambda gets certificate_id but does not get client_id

```
{  
       "client_id":"N/A",
       "certificateId":"",
       "caCertificateId":"",
       "timestamp":"",
       "certificateStatus":"PENDING_ACTIVATION",
       "awsAccountId":"",
       "certificateRegistrationTimestamp":""
}
```

- afterwards on publishing any topic I can get client_id but does not get certificate_id

I've tried to get client_id by this rule when first time client make connection to IoT.

```
SELECT clientId() as client_id , * FROM '$aws/events/certificates/registered/111111111111111'
```

On Lambda I print event:

```
{ 
    client_id: 'N/A',
    certificateId: '222222',
    caCertificateId: '111111111111111',
    timestamp: 3333,
    certificateStatus: 'PENDING_ACTIVATION',
    awsAccountId: '44444',
    certificateRegistrationTimestamp: '55555'
}
```

here "1111.." is my CA certificate.

I want to get certificate_id so that I can active or deactive device using boto3 iot function

```
response = client.update_certificate(
    certificateId='string',
    newStatus='ACTIVE'|'INACTIVE'
)
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iot.html#IoT.Client.update_certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to connect events on the topic 
$aws/events/presence/connected/+

This will allow you to correlate client Id to principal id (certificate).

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html